# How to show Firebase Streamview to our users

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

It turns out Firebase Streamview offers a real nice insight into where my product is used right now. I am thinking if it is possible to show this map to public,without any need for them to have special access to Firebase? E.g., with an API or some public URL.

[image]

Comment: There is no public API for this.

Comment: Thanks Doug. I will edit if/when this feature becomes available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Doug's comment, there is currently no way to show this to non-Firebase users.